# Increase row height in Table

Tags: tables, multirow

I have the following table:

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
\caption{Table Type Styles}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|S|K|c|S|Z|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering mmMAGIC UMi} & LOS & $\begin{aligned} PL_{\textnormal{UMi-LOS}} = 32.9 + 19.2\log_{10}(d_{3D}) + 20.8\log_{10}(f_{c}) \end{aligned}$ & 2 & \multirow{3}{*}{$\begin{aligned}
                    6 <       f_c<100 \text{ GHz} \\
                    1.5\leq      h_{\text{UE}}\leq3\text{ m} \\
                    1.5\leq      h_{\text{BS}}\leq10\text{ m}
                    \end{aligned}$} \\ \cline{2-4}
& NLOS & $\begin{aligned} PL_{\textnormal{UMi-NLOS}} =31.0 + 45.0\log_{10}(d_{3D}) + 20.0\log_{10}(f_{c})\end{aligned}$ & 7.82 & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:models}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

and after compiling:
[image: pic]
How can I adjust the row height to fit the last column?

Comment: Could you please post a complete (compilable) code?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your  document class is one of the standard ones, and the paper format the default, your table won't fit within the  document width. So either  you print your table sideways, or you reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, split the equations in the middle column over  two lines, and add some vertical padding with the `cellspace` package. I also changed the last column type to `c`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

 \begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}}
\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Table Type Styles}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|S|K|Oc|S|c|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{=}{\centering mmMAGIC UMi} & LOS & $\begin{aligned} PL_{\textnormal{UMi-LOS}} = 32.9 & + 19.2\log_{10}(d_{3D})\\ & + 20.8\log_{10}(f_{c}) \end{aligned}$ & 2
& \multirow{4}{*}{$\begin{aligned}
6 & < f_c<\SI{100}{\GHz} \\
1.5 & \leq h_{\text{UE}}\leq3\text{\,m} \\
1.5 & \leq h_{\text{BS}}\leq10\text{\,m}
\end{aligned}$} \\ \cline{2-4}
& NLOS & $\begin{aligned} PL_{\textnormal{UMi-NLOS}} =31.0 & + 45.0\log_{10}(d_{3D})\\ & + 20.0\log_{10}(f_{c})\end{aligned}$ & 7.82 & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:models}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your multirow command in the last column spanned three rows, but your table has only two rows. If you add a row, your table works. However, your table is too wide for the margins, and the columns too narrow for the cell content. Therefore, your code generates overfull hbox warnings, and the table protrud into the right margin. I have reduced the space between columns and the fontsize to get rid of the warnings.

If you want to remove the vertical lines between the first four cells in the last row, just change the last row to read

```
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} &\\\hline
```

I have also removed some unnecessary code.

In example two, I have added code to typeset the tabular using nested tabular and [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, amsmath, caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin {document}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{K}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Table Type Styles\label{tab:models}}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|S|K|c|S|Z|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering mmMAGIC UMi} & LOS & $PL_{\textnormal{UMi-LOS}} = 32.9 + 19.2\log_{10}(d_{3D}) + 20.8\log_{10}(f_{c}) $ & 2 & \multirow{3}{*}{$\begin{aligned}
                    6 <       f_c<100 \text{ GHz} \\
                    1.5\leq      h_{\text{UE}}\leq3\text{ m} \\
                    1.5\leq      h_{\text{BS}}\leq10\text{ m}
                    \end{aligned}$} \\ \cline{2-4}
& NLOS & $PL_{\textnormal{UMi-NLOS}} =31.0 + 45.0\log_{10}(d_{3D}) + 20.0\log_{10}(f_{c})$ & 7.82 & \\\cline{1-4}
&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\begin{table}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\centering
\caption{Table Type Styles\label{tab:models-ii}}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cccc@{}}

mmMAGIC & LOS & $PL_{\textnormal{UMi-LOS}} = 32.9 + 19.2\log_{10}(d_{3D}) + 20.8\log_{10}(f_{c}) $ & 2\\
UMi & NLOS & $PL_{\textnormal{UMi-NLOS}} =31.0 + 45.0\log_{10}(d_{3D}) + 20.0\log_{10}(f_{c})$ & 7.82\\

\end{tabular}

&
$\begin{aligned}
                    6 <       f_c<100 \text{ GHz} \\
                    1.5\leq      h_{\text{UE}}\leq3\text{ m} \\
                    1.5\leq      h_{\text{BS}}\leq10\text{ m}
                    \end{aligned}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```